# How to show JQuery UI Date in a format like 25-JAN-15(Month in Capital Letters)?

Tags: jquery, date

How to show JQuery UI Date in a format like 25-JAN-15 with the month name shown in capital letters? I've tried the format as 'd-M-yy' but it results in 25-Jan-15.I want to capitalize the letters of month. Thanks in advance

Comment: .toUpperCase() will do the job

Comment: Can u please tell me how to use .touppercase() for formating the date?

Comment: My code looks like this                                                            $('#datepicker-example1').Zebra_DatePicker({
    direction: true,
       disabled_dates: ['* * * 0,6'],
    format: 'd-M-yy',
    
    
              });

Comment: I've found out the answer. I just changed the Names of months in the calendar to capital letters. And It works !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CSS** using style to achieve month capital letters

```
input.datepicker {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**JS**

$('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-y' });

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' class='datepicker'>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a26masmh/1/)**

here http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ is complete reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `months_abbr` setting and provide your abbriviations in upper case to accomplish that:

```
$('.datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker({ 
    direction: true, 
    disabled_dates: ['* * * 0,6'], 
    format: 'd-M-yy', 
    months_abbr: ['JAN', //todo other months...]
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7foxkfya/)